# Hibernate doesn't find setter for a property (org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to get the result of an SQL query in my transactional class (Spring annotation):

```
String query = "SELECT DAT, DROP_RADIO FROM My_TABLE";
SQLQuery q = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query);

q.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CallDrop.class));
List result = q.list();
```

And CallDrop:

```
public class CallDrop implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private Date dat;
    private BigDecimal onRadio;
    public BigDecimal getOnRadio() {
        return onRadio;
    }
    public void setOnRadio(BigDecimal onRadio) {
        this.onRadio = onRadio;
    }
    public Date getDat() {
        return dat;
    }
    public void setDat(Date dat) {
        this.dat = dat;
    }
}
```

The .hbm.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.company.beans.CallDrop" table="My_TABLE">
        <id name="id" type="int" />

        <property name="dat" type="date">
            <column name="DAT" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="onRadio" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="DROP_RADIO" precision="22" scale="0" />
        </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I'm sure that I've added the hbm.xml to the applicationContext file, in the session factory:

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryETL" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSourceETL"/></property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
                    <value>com/company/beans/CallDrop.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

So, there is no type but it doesn't work. Does any body know what is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: you are mapping to kpi_network_bh and querying over My_Table.Is it by mistake?

Comment: It was just a mistake when publishing the question

Comment: @DonRoby it is a new feature in stackoverflow :)

Comment: No. I'm stucked in this error!

Comment: could you post the exact exception? which property is causing the exception?

Comment: @mata: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for DAT on class com.company.beans.CallDrop

Answer (score 3):

You can use addScalar(String columnAlias, Type type) to explicitly declare the column alias of your native SQL:

```
getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select e.id AS id, e.first_name AS firstName, e.password AS password FROM table")
                .addScalar("id", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER )
                .addScalar("firstName", StandardBasicTypes.STRING )
                .addScalar("password", StandardBasicTypes.STRING )
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Employee.class))
                .list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change query to  `"SELECT DAT as \"dat\", DROP_RADIO as \"onRadio\" FROM My_TABLE"`